# How to use HUnit in Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a stackproject `stapro` with a file `app/Main.hs`

```
module Main where

import Lib

main = putStrLn "This is main" 

foo::Int ->Int
foo = (+1)
```

and a file `test/Spec.hs`

```
module Spec where

import Test.HUnit
import Main (foo)

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Test suite not yet implemented"

testFoo :: Test
testFoo = TestCase $ assertEqual "Should return 2" 2 (foo 1)
```

When I try to execute the tests however

```
$ stack test
While constructing the BuildPlan the following exceptions were encountered:

--  While attempting to add dependency,
    Could not find package Main in known packages

--  Failure when adding dependencies:    
      Main: needed (-any), stack configuration has no specified version
    needed for package stapro-0.1.0.0
```

My .cabal file is

```
name:                stapro
version:             0.1.0.0
...
build-type:          Simple
-- extra-source-files:
cabal-version:       >=1.10

library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lib
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
  default-language:    Haskell2010

executable stapro-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base
                     , stapro
  default-language:    Haskell2010

test-suite stapro-test
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:      test
  main-is:             Spec.hs
  build-depends:       base
                     , stapro
                     , HUnit
                     , Main
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  default-language:    Haskell2010

...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to depend on the executable (`Main` in `build-depends` of the `test-suite` section), so that you can test it in your test suite. That doesn't work, in fact you can't really test your executable at all.

Remove `Main` from the `build-depends`. Move all the code you want to test into your library.